# change nested array object to objects by value type in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops

How to modify the array object to object in javascript.

I have object `obj1`, change the value of details key to new object javascript

```
function newObj(obj1){
  return Object.assign({}, ...obj1.map(e=>(e.details)));
}
var r1= this.newObj(obj1)

var obj1 = [
  {
    details: {
      "info":["stocks","finance",""],
      "sales":["analytics"]
    }
  }
]

var obj2 = [
  {
    details: {
      "city":{"SG"}
    }
  }
]
Expected Output
//for obj1 (show only first value of array)
{
  stocks: "stocks",
  analytics: "analytics"
}
//obj2
{
SG: "SG"
}
```

Comment: Also, `cities:{"MY,IN"}` is not syntactically valid.

Comment: Still, `"city":{"SG,IN"}` is not a valid object notation. Do you mean `"city":["SG,IN"]`?

Comment: @Terry thanks for reply, and updated code,its object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object in `obj2` should have keys.

To solve this problem, we need to keep an object/map to fill it with the values to be returned by the function. Therefore, you need to iterate over each `detail` element and get the values of each property. Then, we can check whether it's an `array` or `object` and fill the `map` accordingly:

```js
var obj1 = [
  {
    details: {
      "info":["stocks","finance",""],
      "sales":["analytics"]
    }
  }
]
var obj2 = [
  {
    details: {
      "city":{name:"SG"}
    }
  }
]

function newObj(obj1){
  let map = {};
  obj1.forEach(e=>{
    let details = e.details;
    Object.values(details).forEach(value => {
      if(Array.isArray(value) && value.length>0)
        map[value[0]]=value[0];
      else if(typeof value === 'object')
        Object.values(value).forEach(val => { map[val]=val; });
    })
  });
  return map;
}

var r1= this.newObj(obj1)
console.log(r1);
var r2 = this.newObj(obj2)
console.log(r2);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, want to show only first value of field in array `{
  "stocks": "stocks",
  "analytics": "analytics"
}`

Comment: @ved you need to update the expected output. Should this rule apply for the object case also (take only the first element in object)?

Comment: Badwi thanks for reply,  this rule should be applicable only for array

Comment: @Badwi, how to change output like this{   "info": "stocks",   "sales": "analytics" } and {city: "SG"}